# Question about Trusted Service Paths

Tags: privilege-escalation, windows-7

I am studying Computing Security, and I was reading [this](http://toshellandback.com/2015/11/24/ms-priv-esc/) article about Windows privilege escalation. I tried to run the following command on my own Windows machine to see if I had some "**Trusted Service Paths**" issue:

```
wmic service get name,displayname,pathname,startmode |findstr /i "Auto" |findstr /i /v "C:\Windows\\" |findstr /i /v """
```

And I got the following output:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld
```

So I don't get it, the command above was supose to find out paths with "spaces" in it (like `C:\wamp\bin\Some Folder\` for instance), but here I can just see dots. So my question is: are folder names with dots vulnerable to **Trusted Service Path attack** ?

(meaning, if I put a mysql5.exe in mysql folder, will Windows parse/execute it also when trying to reach **mysqld.exe** ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unquoted service paths are only vulnerable if they contain spaces. That is because Windows would handle the space as a break and pass the rest of the service path as an argument.

Original path:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld
```

If the path would look this way:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5 6.17\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld
```

Windows would first try:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.exe 6.17\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld
```

and if there's a file with that name there, it would try to execute it otherwise Windows would try the rest of the service path until next space or the end, depending on if there's an argument or not.

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5 6.17\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld
```

By quoting the service path you define the correct path, everything there after is handled as arguments.

```
"C:\Quoted\Service\Path.exe" <argument>
```